# Update Quote Item before Saving to Quote Item Table

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Is there a way to modify the value of the Quote item/Product item before being saved in the Quote Item table? Let say I added a product in the cart, I can see that this product is added in the Quote Item Table in the DB. Now what I want is update that value first before saving it in the DB. So basically I want to make the value of the item `is_virtual` set to 1. The original Product is set to `is_virtual` = 0 but what I want is when I add this product to cart I want to update the value in the `Quote_item` table for column `is_virtual` and set it to 1. How can I achieve this? I think it can be done via plugin or observer? Like before_set_product or something. Is this possible and available? How do I do this?

Update:
Just for reference I followed this same idea

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="set_is_virtual" instance="Vendor\Checkout\Observer\UpdateIsVirtual" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And the observer is like this

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Checkout\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class UpdateIsVirtual implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
    
        $item->setIsVirtual(1);
    }

}
```

This doesn't update the entry in the Quote Item table. I want the entry in the Quote Item table to be updated as well as it's the most important thing I need to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is_virtual is set on beforeSave in Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item. So you would need a plugin after beforeSave

```
/**
 * Quote Item Before Save prepare data process
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function beforeSave()
{
    parent::beforeSave();
    $this->setIsVirtual($this->getProduct()->getIsVirtual());
    if ($this->getQuote()) {
        $this->setQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Create a plugin as below

File: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
        <plugin name="vendorname_modulename_set_is_virtual" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\SetQuoteItemIsVirtual"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

File: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/SetQuoteItemIsVirtual.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

/**
 * Set quote item is virtual
 */
class SetQuoteItemIsVirtual
{
    /**
     * @param Item $subject
     */
    public function afterBeforeSave(Item $subject)
    {
        $subject->setIsVirtual(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this approach but when I check the database it didn't update the record in the DB. That's the most important thing I want to do. I want to update the record in the DB

Comment: I have edited the answer. Try this new solution.

Comment: I want to save during go to checkout, not to load cart page only.